# requests GET saves not entirely file

Tags: python, api

Need to download artefact from Artifactory, using [Artifactory REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RetrieveArtifact).

My code is:

```
with open(jfrog_testfile, 'wb') as outfile:
    data = requests.get(baseurl, auth=(jfrog_user, jfrog_pswd), stream=True)
    shutil.copyfileobj(data.raw, outfile)
    data.raise_for_status()
```

And another one attempt with same result:

```
with open(jfrog_testfile, 'wb') as outfile:
    data = requests.get(baseurl, auth=(jfrog_user, jfrog_pswd), stream=True)
    for chunk in data.iter_content(65536):
        outfile.write(chunk)
    data.raise_for_status()
```

`baseurl` is correct, i.e.:

```
baseurl = os.path.join(jfrog_url, jfrog_api, jfrog_repo, jfrog_tetstdir, jfrog_testfile)

print(baseurl)
```

returns:

```
https://project.artifactoryonline.com/project/api/storage/project-releases-local/ppp/artefact.war
```

Problem is - exactly artefact size is 5.7 MB, but after that reqeust - I got only 841 bytes:

```
$ ls -l artefact.war 
-rw-r--r--  1 username  staff  841 Jan 21 11:47 artefact.war
```

Even if I run same request with `curl -o` - I have same 841 bytes.
Using `wget` - I have whole file, 5,7 MB.

What's wrong with m(e)y request?

Answer (score 1):

My error was in URL for GET.

URL consist from:

```
jfrog_url = 'https://project.artifactoryonline.com/project/'
jfrog_api = 'api/storage/'
jfrog_repo = 'project-releases-local'
jfrog_tetstdir = 'artefact'
jfrog_testfile = 'artefact.war'
```

And:

`baseurl = os.path.join(jfrog_url, jfrog_repo, jfrog_tetstdir, jfrog_testfile)`

For `GET` don't need insert `jfrog_api` in request.

So, instead of:

`requests.get('https://project.artifactoryonline.com/project/api/storage/project-releases-local/ppp/artefact.war')`

must be used:

`requests.get(https://project.artifactoryonline.com/project/project-releases-local/ppp/artefact.war')`.

`'api/storage/'` will be necessary for `PUT`/`POST` requests, as I remember.